# ServiceM8 api email - how to relate to job diary

Tags: email

I can send an email from a ServiceM8 account through the ServiceM8 API 'message services' (http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/platform-services/message-services/), and read the resulting ServiceM8 message-id.

But I would like to relate that message to a specific job within ServiceM8, so that it will appear as an email item in that job's diary in the ServiceM8 web application.  (Emails sent from within the ServiceM8 web application are related to the diary and appear there - my question is about how to do this from the API).

Worst case, I could create a new 'Note' containing the email text and add that to the job in the hope that it would show up in the diary in the web application as a note.

But I want to check there isn't an easier way since sending the email results in there already being a relatable message-id available within ServiceM8.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the messaging services API, can't be done.  Using the web API, you can do just that.

There's an authorisation code required, which is specific to your account and to this function, you only need to retrieve it once, and then you can integrate that specific URL into your code.  It's contained within the ClientSidePlatform_PerSessionSetup URL.

Here is a script that will grab the E-mail URL specific to your login:

**Syntax:** `./getsm8emailurl.sh "email@address.com" "password"`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#getsm8emailurl.sh

#Create Basic auth 
user="$1"
pass="$2"
pass="$(echo -n "${pass}" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' ')"
auth="$(echo -n "${user}:${pass}" | base64)"

#Get Account specific e-mail url
email_url="https://go.servicem8.com/$(curl --compressed -s -L "https://go.servicem8.com/$(curl --compressed -s -L "https://go.servicem8.com/" -H "Authorization: Basic $auth" | grep -o 'ClientSidePlatform_PerSessionSetup.[^"]*' | grep -v "s_boolFailover")" -H "Authorization: Basic $auth" | grep -o "PluginEmailClient_SendEmail.[^']*")"

#Output base e-mail URL
echo "$email_url"
```

Once you have the email url, (will start with `https://go.servicem8.com/PluginEmailClient_SendEmail` and will end with the s_auth code), you can use it like any other rest endpoint.

**Required Header Values:**

- Authorization (same as regular API)

**Required Post Params:**

- **s_form_values**=`"guid-to-cc-subject-msg-job_id-attachedFiles-attachedContacts-strRegardingObjectUUID-strRegardingObject-boolAllowDirectReply"`
  (these have to stay just as they are)
- **s_auth**="your_account_s_auth_code"
- **to**="recipient@domain.com"

**Optional Post Params:**

- **subject**="subject"
- **msg**="html message body"
- **boolAllowDirectReply**="true|false" (Can recipient reply directly to job diary)
- **strRegardingObject**="job|company"
- **strRegardingObjectUUID**="job|company uuid"

---

### DEMO

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#sendemail.sh
#demo here using random auth codes and uuids

curl --compressed -s "https://go.servicem8.com/PluginEmailClient_SendEmail" \
-H "Authorization: Basic dGVzdHVzZXJAdGVzdGRvbWFpbi5jb206dGVzdHBhc3M=" \
-d s_form_values=guid-to-cc-subject-msg-job_id-attachedFiles-attachedContacts-strRegardingObjectUUID-strRegardingObject-boolAllowDirectReply \
-d s_auth="6akj209db12bikbs01hbobi3r0fws7j2" \
-d boolAllowDirectReply=true \
-d strRegardingObject=job \
-d strRegardingObjectUUID="512b3b2a-007e-431b-be23-4bd812f2aeaf" \
-d to="test@testdomain.com" \
-d subject="Job Diary E-mail" \
-d msg="hello"
```

---

*Edit/Update/Disclaimer:
This information is for convenience and efficiency - memos, quick tasks, notifications, updates, etc.  This isn't to be relied upon for critical business operations as it is undocumented, and since it does not process JS like a browser would, it could stop working if the inner workings of the service changed.*